# Remote Desktop Into A locked Computer

Tags: remote-desktop

Can you remote desktop into a logged in computer thats locked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to enable Concurrent remote desktop patch. Apply the patch present here https://web.archive.org/web/20110408224829/http://thegreenbutton.com/forums/t/79427.aspx it contains the source code if you like to know exactly what it is doing. I am using this patch in almost every machine that pass to my hands. Then you could login no matter what user is connected, and you could even log with the same account of an already connected user.

To check this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and in the tab of User see the actual connected users. It doesn't kick off anybody. You could administer the PC with other user working at the same time.

Comment: "*you could even log with the same account of an already connected user*" This sounds sketchy/suspicious. Windows should not allow you to create a second session with the same credentials as an existing session.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using Windows.

It depends on the settings on the computer and the account you are using to log in.  If you are an administrator, you can kick them off. If you're the user that locked the computer, then you'll just log in as that user and resume your session.

If you are not an Administrator, I think that they have to let you on if they are currently logged on.  It kinda depends on your setup.  There are remote desktop settings that you can change, like adding users to the list of approved users, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a user with this issue going from a windows 10 OS to a windows 7 OS at work.  Remote Desktop Connection would not allow her to access her work system and gave the three reasons it gives when the computer is off.  I pinged her computer on the network and system was on and actively responding.  I used Remote Control Viewer to Remote into her work system and noticed that the system was locked and not logged off.  I read around the internet and found a lot of answers like these on here for admin, which I don't have.  I sent the work computer a ctrl alt delete command through Remote Control Viewer under Actions and it brought the work system to the user log in.  I had the user try to reconnect through Remote Desktop Connection and it connected successfully.  I am not sure if this helps out, but this was something that just happened to me and my best guess solution, stab in the dark try, that was able to resolve the issue.